# Local web server html page not beig processed by php

Tags: php, docker, apache2

First off the bat I'll be honest and say that I have very little idea what I am doing, so I might be going about this all wrong.

Anyways, I am running this local web server with apache in a docker container.
I am using the httpd2.4 image as a base. In my dockerfile, among others, I have the line:

```
RUN apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.3 -y
```

to get the php module.
The module shows up when I use the `apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES` command.
However when I look in the httpd/modules folder i cannot find any php related modules.

In my .htaccess I also added the `AddType application/x-httpd-php7.3 .html` expression. I also tried with AddHandeler instead, without the version nuber and without the dot in the version number after looking around for a bit.
In all cases the web still works and i dont get any errors, but the php still inst processed

I have a html page with some php script inside it, and if I use php manually to run it it works as expected.
However if I access it from the web server it does nothing.

I know this is fairly convoluted and probably pretty badly explained, but I don't know how to explain it better without going into too much detail.

As requested, here is the dockerfile:

```
FROM httpd:2.4
ADD httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/ 
ADD .htpasswd /etc/pass/ 
ADD test-wall-web /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ 
ADD GoldenGateTool/main /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/Protected
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.3 -y
```

So, update:
The module is loaded, the module is enabled, the filematch is set in the php config file and its still not working

If i have `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php7.3 .html` in my .htaccess file it prompts me to download the html page instead of viewing it when going to the url

Comment: plz, post here your Dockerfile

Comment: @MeiramChuzhenbayev There you go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so there seemed to be multiple problems.
Apparently the module .so file was located under `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/` instead of `/usr/local/apache2/modules/`
Not sure why exactly there are two duplicate module folders, which both had all the standard modules in them, but any new modules added would only be added on the one in library.

Second thing was i needed to use both settype and sethandeler in the .htaccess file
as such:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```